# Improving DOC2VEC Gensim efficiency

Tags: python, nltk, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I am trying to train Gensim Doc2Vec model on tagged documents. I have around 4000000 documents. Following is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import logging
from tqdm import tqdm
from gensim.models import Doc2Vec
from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedDocument
import os
import re



def text_process(text):
    logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s: %(message)s", datefmt='%H:%M:%S', level=logging.INFO)
    stop_words_lst = ['mm', 'machine', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'first', 'second', 'third', 'plurality', 'one', 'more', 'least', 'at', 'example', 'memory', 'exemplary', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth','a', 'A', 'an', 'the', 'system', 'method', 'apparatus', 'computer', 'program', 'product', 'instruction', 'code', 'configure', 'operable', 'couple', 'comprise', 'comprising', 'includes', 'cm', 'processor', 'hardware']
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

    temp_corpus =[]
    text = re.sub(r'\d+', '', text)
    for w in stop_words_lst:
        stop_words.add(w)
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    word_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
    lemmatizer= WordNetLemmatizer()
    for w in word_tokens:
        w = lemmatizer.lemmatize(w)
        if w not in stop_words:
            temp_corpus.append(str(w))
    return temp_corpus

chunk_patent = pd.DataFrame()
chunksize = 10 ** 5
cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
directory = os.getcwd()
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
       if file.startswith("patent_cpc -"):
           print(file)
           #f=open(file, 'r')
           #f.close()
           for chunk_patent_temp in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=chunksize):
                #chunk_patent.sort_values(by=['cpc'], inplace=True)
                #chunk_patent_temp = chunk_patent_temp[chunk_patent_temp['cpc'] == "G06K7"]
                if chunk_patent.empty:
                    chunk_patent = chunk_patent_temp
                else:
                    chunk_patent = chunk_patent.append(chunk_patent_temp)
train_tagged = chunk_patent.apply(lambda r: TaggedDocument(words=text_process(r['text']), tags=[r.cpc]), axis=1)
print(train_tagged.values)

if os.path.exists("cpcpredict_doc2vec.model"):
    doc2vec_model = Doc2Vec.load("cpcpredict_doc2vec.model")
    doc2vec_model.build_vocab((x for x in tqdm(train_tagged.values)), update=True)
    doc2vec_model.train(train_tagged, total_examples=doc2vec_model.corpus_count, epochs=50)
    doc2vec_model.save("cpcpredict_doc2vec.model")
else:
    doc2vec_model = Doc2Vec(dm=0, vector_size=300, min_count=100, workers=cores-1)
    doc2vec_model.build_vocab((x for x in tqdm(train_tagged.values)))
    doc2vec_model.train(train_tagged, total_examples=doc2vec_model.corpus_count, epochs=50)
    doc2vec_model.save("cpcpredict_doc2vec.model")
```

I have tried modifying the Doc2vec parameters but without any luck.

On the same data I have trained Word2vec model, which is much accurate in comparison to the doc2vec model. Further, "most_similar" results for word2vec model is very different from the doc2vec model.

Following is the code for searching most similar results:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import logging
from gensim.models import Doc2Vec
import re

def text_process(text):
    logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s: %(message)s", datefmt='%H:%M:%S', level=logging.INFO)
    stop_words_lst = ['mm', 'machine', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'first', 'second', 'third', 'example', 'memory', 'exemplary', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth','a', 'A', 'an', 'the', 'system', 'method', 'apparatus', 'computer', 'program', 'product', 'instruction', 'code', 'configure', 'operable', 'couple', 'comprise', 'comprising', 'includes', 'cm', 'processor', 'hardware']
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    #for index, row in df.iterrows():
    temp_corpus =[]
    text = re.sub(r'\d+', '', text)
    for w in stop_words_lst:
        stop_words.add(w)
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    word_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
    lemmatizer= WordNetLemmatizer()
    for w in word_tokens:
        w = lemmatizer.lemmatize(w)
        if w not in stop_words:
            temp_corpus.append(str(w))
    return temp_corpus

model = Word2Vec.load("cpc.model")
print(model.most_similar(positive=['barcode'], topn=30))

model1 = Doc2Vec.load("cpcpredict_doc2vec.model")

pred_tags = model1.most_similar('barcode',topn=10)
print(pred_tags)
```

Further, the output of the aforementioned is cited below:

```
[('indicium', 0.36468246579170227), ('symbology', 0.31725651025772095), ('G06K17', 0.29797130823135376), ('dataform', 0.29535001516342163), ('rogue', 0.29372256994247437), ('certification', 0.29178398847579956), ('reading', 0.27675414085388184), ('indicia', 0.27346929907798767), ('Contra', 0.2700084149837494), ('redemption', 0.26682156324386597)]

[('searched', 0.4693435728549957), ('automated', 0.4469209909439087), ('production', 0.4364866018295288), ('hardcopy', 0.42193126678466797), ('UWB', 0.4197841286659241), ('technique', 0.4149003326892853), ('authorized', 0.4134449362754822), ('issued', 0.4129987359046936), ('installing', 0.4093806743621826), ('thin', 0.4016669690608978)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Doc2Vec` mode you've chosen, `dm=0` (aka plain "PV-DBOW"), does not train word-vectors at all. Word vectors will still be randomly-initialized, due to shared code-paths of the different models, but never trained and thus meaingless.

So the results of your `most_similar()`, using a word as the query, will be essentially random. (Using `most_similar()` on the model itself, rather than its `.wv` word-vectors or `.docvecs` doc-vectors, should also be generating a deprecation warning.)

If you need your `Doc2Vec` model to train word-vectors in addition to the doc-vectors, use either the `dm=1` mode ("PV-DM") or `dm=0, dbow_words=1` (adding optional interleaved skip-gram word training to plain DBOW training). In both cases, words will be trained very similarly to a `Word2Vec` model (of the 'CBOW' or 'skip-gram' modes, respectively) – so your word-based `most_similar()` results should then be very comparable.

Separately:

- if you have enough data to train 300-dimensional vectors, & discard all words with fewer than 100 occurrences, then 50 training epochs *may* be more than needed.
- those `most_similar()` results don't particularly look like they're result of any lemmatization, as seems intended by your `text_process()` method, but maybe that's not an issue, or some other issue entirely. Note, though, that with sufficient data, lemmatization may be a superfluous step - all variants of the same word tend to wind up usefully near each other, when there are plenty of varied examples of al the word variants in real contexts.

Comment: Another query
I have around 7000 unique tags in the data set I am using. Does the efficiency of Doc2Vec model decreases because of large of number unique tags?

Comment: Only you can answer that question, as it will depend on your text, tags, and project-specific meaning of 'efficiency'. But note that the typical/original description of `Doc2Vec` (as the 'Paragraph Vector' algorithm) tended to give every document its own unique ID tag, so if you were following that precedent, you'd have 4000000 tags. Using only 7000 unique tags to some extent is like working with only 7000 unique virtual documents (each the concatenation of all your same-tageed docs). That may variety not be sufficient to drive 300-dimensional doc-vectors.

Comment: So, why are there only 7000 document-tags for 4000000 different documents? (How large is each document? What's the ultimate goal of the doc-vectors, if each of the 4000000 docs isn't getting its own unique doc-vector?

Comment: I understand the issue now. I was trying to train doc2vec vectors against the tags and then running classification algorithm on top of it. However the accuracy of such technique of very low (~3.2%). Thereafter, i tried training classifier on the same dataset using logistic regression but again the accuracy of very less. Thereafter, i tried training the model just on three tags, and the accuracy jumped to 71%. Hence, I came to conclusion that probably the number of tags reduces the accuracy of the system.

Comment: Certainly, classifying a text into a single correct class out of 7000 possible answers is harder than into 1 correct class out of 3. But a lot would depend on your choices, including algorithms, parameters, & preprocessing. As previously mentioned, if you are only supplying 7K unique tags, rather than 4M, you essentially collapsed your training set to just 7K larger docs, which may have diluted lots of the meaningful variability from the original docs. Much higher accuracy might be possible, but it's impossible to guess what else might be suboptimal in your many unshown classification steps.

Comment: Further, with 7000 distinct classes, perhaps classifying texts exactly right isn't as important as ensuring the 'right' class is among the top-N predictions of the classifier, mixed in with many other of the most-similar classes. (It's uncommon for such classes to be truly disjoint, or so distinct that even a human expert could classify them just right using only info in the natural-language text.)